# java: WbSocket: How to implement wss in org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server?

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, websocket, dropwizard, wss

I have a dropwizard application that I have used for my REST API which is hosted in AWS EC2 Server. (maven project)

I have also implemented websocket (org.glassfish.tyrus) as a service in it.

```
org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server wsServer;

wsServer = new org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server(
            "localhost",
            port,
            getContextPath(),
            null,
            ServerEndpoint.class
    );
```

`wsServer.start();`

Everything is working.
Except the part when I try to add wss support in it.

I haven't found anything significant in internet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you describe what's wrong? Is there any significant error? Can you provide some code extract so it may help to find if there is an erroneous configuration?

Comment: hi @ASE. Its just a simple code. this is working fine with ws:// but now i want to access this via wss://

Comment: hi @ASE. Its just a simple code. this is working fine with ws:// but now i want to access this via wss://